# Intersecting two sets, retaining all (up to) three parts efficiently

Tags: python, set

If you have two sets `a` and `b` and intersect them, there are three interesting parts (which may be empty): h(ead) elements of `a` not in `b`, i(ntersection) elements in both `a` and `b`, and t(ail) elements of `b` not in `a`.

For example: `{1, 2, 3} & {2, 3, 4}` -> `h:{1}, i:{2, 3}, t:{4}` (not actual Python code, clearly)

One very clean way to code that in Python:

```
h, i, t = a - b, a & b, b - a
```

I figure that this can be slightly more efficient though:

```
h, t = a - (i := a & b), b - i
```

Since it first computes the intersection and then subtracts only that from `a` and then `b`, which would help if `i` is small and `a` and `b` are large - although I suppose it depends on the implementation of the subtraction whether it's truly faster. It's not likely to be worse, as far as I can tell.

I was unable to find such an operator or function, but since I can imagine efficient implementations that would perform the three-way split of `a` and `b` into `h`, `i`, and `t` in fewer iterations, am I missing something like this, which may already exist?

```
from magical_set_stuff import hit

h, i, t = hit(a, b)
```

Comment: A quick test I did: `h, t = a - (i := a & b), b - i` is ~1.5-2x faster than `h, i, t = a - b, a & b, b - a`. Surprisingly `h, i, t = a - (a & b), a & b, b - (a & b)` is slightly but consistently faster than the second approach. A loopy approach that creates `h` and `i` by iterating over `a` and membership checks in `b` predictably performs worse (2-6x) than the first approach

Comment: That is genuinely surprising  - maybe some underwater optimisation going on there, because I can't think why accessing and use `i` twice would be slower than re-evaluating `(a & b)` two more times.

Comment: just to clarify: the approach that subtracts `a - b` and `b - a` is slightly slower than `a - (a & b)` and `b - (a & b)`, which is surprising since the intersection needs to be calculated twice. `a - i, b - i` is always faster than both.

Comment: Ah, thanks - because I just ran a test myself, and those solution compared roughly as `4.3:2.4:3.6`, so I agree the `a - i, b - i` approach is faster by a decent margin. Writing looping solutions in Python I can get to about 4.6, but I can't beat any of the above. A C function might be able to of course.

Comment: I guess we could also use only `set.difference`: `t = b - (i:= a - (h:= a - b))`. It seems this one performs faster when the intersection is big.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in Python, and I haven't seen such a thing in a 3rd-party library either.

Here's a perhaps unexpected approach that's largely insensitive to which sets are bigger than others, and to how much overlap among inputs there may be. I dreamed it up when facing a related problem: suppose you had 3 input sets, and wanted to derive the 7 interesting sets of overlaps (in A only, B only, C only, both A and B, both A and C, both B and C, or in all 3). This version strips that down to the 2-input case. In general, assign a unique power of 2 to each input, and use those as bit flags:

```
def hit(a, b):
    x2flags = defaultdict(int)
    for x in a:
        x2flags[x] = 1
    for x in b:
        x2flags[x] |= 2
    result = [None, set(), set(), set()]
    for x, flag in x2flags.items():
        result[flag].add(x)
    return result[1], result[3], result[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I won't accept my own answer unless nobody manages to beat my own solution or any of the good and concise Python ones.

But for anyone interested in some numbers:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit


def grismar(a: set, b: set):
    h, i, t = set(), set(), b.copy()
    for x in a:
        if x in t:
            i.add(x)
            t.remove(x)
        else:
            h.add(x)
    return h, i, t


def good(a: set, b: set):
    return a - b, a & b, b - a


def better(a: set, b: set):
    h, t = a - (i := a & b), b - i
    return h, i, t


def ok(a: set, b: set):
    return a - (a & b), a & b, b - (a & b)


from collections import defaultdict
def tim(a, b):
    x2flags = defaultdict(int)
    for x in a:
        x2flags[x] = 1
    for x in b:
        x2flags[x] |= 2
    result = [None, set(), set(), set()]
    for x, flag in x2flags.items():
        result[flag].add(x)
    return result[1], result[3], result[2]


def pychopath(a, b):
    h, t = set(), b.copy()
    h_add = h.add
    t_remove = t.remove
    i = {x for x in a
         if x in t and not t_remove(x) or h_add(x)}
    return h, i, t


def enke(a, b):
    t = b - (i := a - (h := a - b))
    return h, i, t


xs = set(randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(10000))
ys = set(randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(10000))

# validation
g = (f(xs, ys) for f in (grismar, good, better, ok, tim, enke))
l = set(tuple(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in t) for t in g)
assert len(l) == 1, 'functions are equivalent'

# warmup, not competing
timeit(lambda: grismar(xs, ys), number=500)

# competition
print('a - b, a & b, b - a ', timeit(lambda: good(xs, ys), number=10000))
print('a - (i := a & b), b - i ', timeit(lambda: better(xs, ys), number=10000))
print('a - (a & b), a & b, b - (a & b) ', timeit(lambda: ok(xs, ys), number=10000))
print('tim ', timeit(lambda: tim(xs, ys), number=10000))
print('grismar ', timeit(lambda: grismar(xs, ys), number=10000))
print('pychopath ', timeit(lambda: pychopath(xs, ys), number=10000))
print('b - (i := a - (h := a - b)) ', timeit(lambda: enke(xs, ys), number=10000))
```

Results:

```
a - b, a & b, b - a  5.6963334
a - (i := a & b), b - i  5.3934624
a - (a & b), a & b, b - (a & b)  9.7732018
tim  16.3080373
grismar  7.709292500000004
pychopath  6.76331460000074
b - (i := a - (h := a - b))  5.197220600000001
```

So far, the optimisation proposed by @enke in the comments appears to win out:

```
t = b - (i := a - (h := a - b))
return h, i, t
```

Edit: added @Pychopath's results, which is indeed substantially faster than my own, although @enke's result is still the one to beat (and likely won't be with just Python). If @enke posts their own answer, I'd happily accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized version of yours, seems to be about 20% faster than yours in your benchmark:

```
def hit(a, b):
    h, t = set(), b.copy()
    h_add = h.add
    t_remove = t.remove
    i = {x for x in a
         if x in t and not t_remove(x) or h_add(x)}
    return h, i, t
```

And you might want to do this at the start, especially if the two sets can have significantly different sizes:

```
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return hit(b, a)[::-1]
```